# Scrape website's Power BI dashboard using R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape my local government's Power BI dashboard using R but it seems like it might be impossible. I've read from the Microsoft site that it is not possible to scrable Power BI dashboards but I am going through several forums showing that it is possible, however I am going through a loop

I am trying to scrape the `Zip Code` tab data from this dashboard:

https://app.powerbigov.us/view?r=eyJrIjoiZDFmN2ViMGEtNzQzMC00ZDU3LTkwZjUtOWU1N2RiZmJlOTYyIiwidCI6IjNiMTg1MTYzLTZjYTMtNDA2NS04NDAwLWNhNzJiM2Y3OWU2ZCJ9&pageName=ReportSectionb438b98829599a9276e2&pageName=ReportSectionb438b98829599a9276e2

I've tried several "techniques" from the given code below

```
scc_webpage <- xml2::read_html("https://app.powerbigov.us/view?r=eyJrIjoiZDFmN2ViMGEtNzQzMC00ZDU3LTkwZjUtOWU1N2RiZmJlOTYyIiwidCI6IjNiMTg1MTYzLTZjYTMtNDA2NS04NDAwLWNhNzJiM2Y3OWU2ZCJ9&pageName=ReportSectionb438b98829599a9276e2&pageName=ReportSectionb438b98829599a9276e2")


# Attempt using xpath
scc_webpage %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="pvExplorationHost"]/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-group/transform/div/div[2]/visual-container-modern[1]/transform/div/div[3]/div/visual-modern/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]') %>% 
  rvest::html_text()

# Attempt using div.<class>
scc_webpage %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes("div.pivotTableCellWrap cell-interactive tablixAlignRight ") %>% 
  rvest::html_text()

# Attempt using xpathSapply
query = '//*[@id="pvExplorationHost"]/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-group/transform/div/div[2]/visual-container-modern[1]/transform/div/div[3]/div/visual-modern/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]'
XML::xpathSApply(xml, query, xmlValue)

scc_webpage %>% 
  html_nodes("ui-view")
```

But I always either get an output saying `character(0)` when using xpath and getting the `div` class and id, or even `{xml_nodeset (0)}` when trying to go through `html_nodes`. The weird thing is that it wouldn't show the whole html of the tableau data when I do:

```
scc_webpage %>% 
  html_nodes("div")
```

And this would be the output, leaving the chunk that I needed blank:

```
{xml_nodeset (2)}
[1] <div id="pbi-loading"><svg version="1.1" class="pulsing-svg-item" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink ...
[2] <div id="pbiAppPlaceHolder">\r\n        <ui-view></ui-view><root></root>\n</div>
```

I guess the issue may be because the numbers are within a series of nested `div` attributes??

The main data I am trying to get are the numbers from the table showing the `Zip code`, `confirmed cases`, `% total cases`, `deaths`, `% total deaths`.

If this is possible to do in R or possibly in Python using Selenium, any help with this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the site you want to analyze relies on JavaScript to run and fetch the content for you. In such a case, `httr::GET` is of no help to you.
However, since manual work is also not an option, we have Selenium.

The following does what you're looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)

library(wdman)
library(RSelenium)
library(xml2)
library(selectr)

# using wdman to start a selenium server
selServ <- selenium(
  port = 4444L,
  version = 'latest',
  chromever = '84.0.4147.30', # set this to a chrome version that's available on your machine
)

# using RSelenium to start chrome on the selenium server
remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = 'localhost',
  port = 4444L,
  browserName = 'chrome'
)

# open a new Tab on Chrome
remDr$open()

# navigate to the site you wish to analyze
report_url <- "https://app.powerbigov.us/view?r=eyJrIjoiZDFmN2ViMGEtNzQzMC00ZDU3LTkwZjUtOWU1N2RiZmJlOTYyIiwidCI6IjNiMTg1MTYzLTZjYTMtNDA2NS04NDAwLWNhNzJiM2Y3OWU2ZCJ9&pageName=ReportSectionb438b98829599a9276e2&pageName=ReportSectionb438b98829599a9276e2"
remDr$navigate(report_url)

# find and click the button leading to the Zip Code data
zipCodeBtn <- remDr$findElement('.//button[descendant::span[text()="Zip Code"]]', using="xpath")
zipCodeBtn$clickElement()

# fetch the site source in XML
zipcode_data_table <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>%
  querySelector("div.pivotTable")
```

Now we have the page source read into R, probably what you had in mind when you started your scraping task.
From here on it's smooth sailing and merely about converting that xml to a useable table:

```
col_headers <- zipcode_data_table %>%
  querySelectorAll("div.columnHeaders div.pivotTableCellWrap") %>%
  map_chr(xml_text)

rownames <- zipcode_data_table %>%
  querySelectorAll("div.rowHeaders div.pivotTableCellWrap") %>%
  map_chr(xml_text)

zipcode_data <- zipcode_data_table %>%
  querySelectorAll("div.bodyCells div.pivotTableCellWrap") %>%
  map(xml_parent) %>%
  unique() %>%
  map(~ .x %>% querySelectorAll("div.pivotTableCellWrap") %>% map_chr(xml_text)) %>%
  setNames(col_headers) %>%
  bind_cols()

# tadaa
df_final <- tibble(zipcode = rownames, zipcode_data) %>%
  type_convert(trim_ws = T, na = c(""))
```

The resulting df looks like this:

```
> df_final
# A tibble: 15 x 5
   zipcode `Confirmed Cases ` `% of Total Cases ` `Deaths ` `% of Total Deaths `
   <chr>                <dbl> <chr>                   <dbl> <chr>               
 1 63301                 1549 17.53%                     40 28.99%              
 2 63366                 1364 15.44%                     38 27.54%              
 3 63303                 1160 13.13%                     21 15.22%              
 4 63385                 1091 12.35%                     12 8.70%               
 5 63304                 1046 11.84%                      3 2.17%               
 6 63368                  896 10.14%                     12 8.70%               
 7 63367                  882 9.98%                       9 6.52%               
 8                        534 6.04%                       1 0.72%               
 9 63348                  105 1.19%                       0 0.00%               
10 63341                   84 0.95%                       1 0.72%               
11 63332                   64 0.72%                       0 0.00%               
12 63373                   25 0.28%                       1 0.72%               
13 63386                   17 0.19%                       0 0.00%               
14 63357                   13 0.15%                       0 0.00%               
15 63376                    5 0.06%                       0 0.00%
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time and effort! This was extremely helpful! Is it possible to do this through manual work without selenium? I was thinking of putting this all into a function to use for another code file, and not sure how to go around this if someone is using a browser other than chrome..

Comment: You have the choice to do this with other browsers, incl. firefox or headless options. `wdman` might help you to download all binaries that you need as well. That would be up to you to research though, I only have experience with Chrome.

Comment: ah okay. And would there be a way to automate this or does the code have to be run each time to update the data?

Comment: I assume you can schedule a cronjob to run it in a script. Take a look at [easily hosting an RStudio machine on AWS](https://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/) and `crontab` to schedule the execution of an Rscript on Linux.

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again, but I've tried working on the code but it keeps giving this error https://snipboard.io/Z20KHF.jpg
Do you have any idea how to go around this or is it just something with my RStudio?

Comment: It tells you that on the site opened by your selenium browser, it does not find a button-tag which contains a span-tag with the text "Zip Code". Are you able to inspect the site opened by your selenium or are you working on a remote machine where the window did not open visibly to you? I'd start by trying to check whether the site has loaded alright (just look into `remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]` which gives you the raw html source. Might also be that due to the dashboard loading for a while, your code is running faster than the button takes to be loaded. `Sys.sleep` helps to pause a bit..

Comment: yes the site does open every time I run it, however I have to change the port everytime. Am I not closing it the right way?

And I've tried running `remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]` but this is the error that is giving me: https://snipboard.io/egUDiG.jpg

And when should the code be sleeping? Right before `remDr$findElement`?

Comment: I can't speak for the port thing, it might be that you would have to stop a running server to free the port. I'm guessing that terminating rstudio would take care of it, but there is an explicit `stop` command too. Let's keep that separate for now. Before checking for the site source or looking for a button, you have to call `remDr$open()` and `remDr$navigate()`. It's after the `navigate`, where you would let the R code wait for a bit to give the JavaScript some time to execute in the browser.

Comment: If the correct site is loading in your selenium tab, that's already great and I'm 100% sure you'll get all the rest to work as well. Once you can see the button you want to click on that selenium browser, you will be able to click it, too. The xpath should be correct, it did work for me, at least. Perhaps don't run the entire script while you're trying to get it to run the first time, but just execute it step by step. If it all works while going through it "slowly", then I think the waiting time is the culprit

Comment: once again, thank you so much for your help!! I was able to work on it to create a nice data frame out of it. If it wasn't for you, my project would've had a big hole of ungathered data. cheers!!

Comment: Haha, I'm happy I could help. Out of curiosity, did you manage to get it working with a headless browser instead of chrome as well? And also, did the scheduling work?

Comment: yes I was able to find a source on the commands to make it headless within R and it worked perfectly with `rsDriver`! I haven't really gotten around with the scheduling yet since I primarily only need to learn how to scrape the dashboard data (I even had help scraping Tableau dashboards too). My project is to create my own dashboard so once I have all the data I need, I will definitely look into hosting an AWS server!!

Comment: @alex_jwb90 - I am able to make it to `remDr$navigate(report_url)`, but am failing to scrape data from a Power BI dashboard. Any recommendations on how to not select any button, but pull the data from the statewide data, say, here: https://app.powerbigov.us/view?r=eyJrIjoiZDgzNTJkNzYtMTNmMy00OTJjLTlhMzctMmZkZDQ2NDQ4YmJiIiwidCI6ImViMTRiMDQ2LTI0YzQtNDUxOS04ZjI2LWI4OWMyMTU5ODI4YyJ9

Comment: @Doughey - for the port issue, use this: `install.packages( 'netstat' )` then `port = free_port()` should work so you don't have to put in a new port each time

Comment: @Kendal thats a stretch - you're on a completely different report there with no simple data table to extract from. To practically approach this: 1) take a look at the POST calls to "https://wabi-us-gov-iowa-api.analysis.usgovcloudapi.net/public/reports/querydata" that are being made while you're navigating the data using your browsers devtools' Network tab. You'll find a lot of those, for each facet of the report. If you monitor which call are sent while you interact, you might identify one that gets the data you want. You can then replicate that in R with `httr::POST` sending the query body

Comment: [... contd.] in case the API raw data works for you, you wouldn't need Selenium altogether. 2) alternatively, like OP, you inspect the rendered dashboard to find the part you're interested in and scrape that (hint: go into the Elements tab of the page inspector, ctrl+f for the text you want to isolate on the page, then right click the element and choose "Copy Selector". You can throw that into R's `querySelector("<HERE>")` like above and extract that _exact_ element in your R code). For the KPIs on the bottom of the page that would work...

Comment: [... contd.2] 2.5) For values like the bar-chart labels, you would probably want to abstract the specific selector a little and use `querySelectorAll` to get all nodes of interest. You could work with xpath & css selection to do something like `read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>% xml_find_first("//div[contains(@aria-label,\"Vaccine doses administered by Week\")]") %>% querySelectorAll("g.labelGraphicsContext > text.label") %>% xml_text()` which leverages the screen reader label to find the correct chart, then digs in to grab the label text nodes' values.

Comment: @alex_jwb90 Hi sir, this answer is very useful. I have a similar issue with a related Power BI dashboard. Maybe if you have time, can you check my question with the issue? This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68596601/web-scraping-power-bi-site-in-r-with-mutiple-sheets-in-dashboard

Comment: If anybody ever encounters this again, I think it's worth mentioning that getting the page source without scrolling will produce a limited amount of matches (I get about 100), which doesn't cover large tables. Check out my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73068560/how-to-get-a-table-from-power-bi-dashboard-using-web-scraping-in-r/73130938#73130938