# Web Scraping PowerBI figure data using RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, powerbi

I am trying to get the underlying data in a powerBI chart. The page allows export as table, but rounded to the integer, and I would like more precision, which is the graph.

"https://app.powerbigov.us/view?r=eyJrIjoiYWQxOTUwODQtOWJiYi00NjRiLWEyNDctMjRiMzJmZGJiZDk4IiwidCI6IjBhZDJkYjBlLTQxZGUtNDNmZS05NDZjLWQyY2FkMDViZDk0ZCJ9"

I can extract the page Source using RSelenium but can't get the right selector for the chart data

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(RSelenium)
```

## using RSelenium to start a chrome on the selenium server

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = 'localhost',
  port = 4445L,
  browserName = 'firefox'
)
```

## open a new Tag on Chrome

```
remDr$open()
```

## navigate to the site I wish to analyze

```
report_url <- "https://app.powerbigov.us/view?r=eyJrIjoiYWQxOTUwODQtOWJiYi00NjRiLWEyNDctMjRiMzJmZGJiZDk4IiwidCI6IjBhZDJkYjBlLTQxZGUtNDNmZS05NDZjLWQyY2FkMDViZDk0ZCJ9"
```

#[Scrape website's Power BI dashboard using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286279/scrape-websites-power-bi-dashboard-using-r)

```
remDr$navigate(report_url)
```

## find and click the button leading to the Code data

```
zipCodeBtn <- remDr$findElement('.//button[descendant::span[text()="Key Metrics"]]', using="xpath")
zipCodeBtn$clickElement()
```

#todo ED Visits for CLI visualContainer

## fetch the site source in XML

```
zipcode_data_table <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>% html_source
```

Other Stack overflow have some examples for tabular PowerBI data, but not a chart.

Thanks

Comment: where do you see more precise figures? I see rounded percentages on that page for `7 Day Average of the Percent of ED visits for CLI and ILI`

Comment: embeded in the y axis of the graph, the values there are more precise

Comment: Can you share the relevant html?  And perhaps an image of this? I cannot see anything but rounded figures when I look at  `7 Day Average of the Percent of ED visits for CLI and ILI`, so am wondering if I am looking at wrong view somehow.

Comment: The whole file is quite long.  This is the <div> container for the heading, but the data is stored in a different variable.            aria-label=\"7 Day Average of the Percent of ED visits for CLI and ILI Area chart\" touch-action=\"auto\">

Comment: data appears to be relative , in variable d ;  d=\"M10,177.3622915601926L11.575324961445252,177.60702339036916L13.150649922890505,177.77173464205455L14.725974884335757,.... 
 ,175.80828063691814\"/><g class=\"cat\"/><g class=\"cat\"/>

Comment: Updates:  When possible to get the data element out from the embedded JSON, I haven't found a better solution than text parsing the string and manually adjusting the scale.  My best semiautomated solution was to save the plot as an image and use the web application : https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/  which works well for line and dot plots

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Goto : apps.automeris.io/wpd
Select: Add File
Choose Plot Type: 2 d xy
Orient axis by picking two well localized points on on x axis and y axis, I used date difference for the date axis, x1 origin 0, x2 countable number of days towards end for calibaration,  picke labelled y points which are close to grid access
Choose complete
Set relative values for 1,x2,y1,y2

I chose box, which aligns yellow box over capture area and automates point selection, then deleted unwanted points, but you can draw a pen trace to focuse capture, or select points

Select color with color picker if multiple series
Click Run, points will be highlighted,
Delete any unwanted points if axis gets selected or grid/labels. Just click Delete, then remove extraneous
Click View data, I exported as CSV

Not fully automated but pretty convenient in the end and flexible.
Compared to the R package 'digitize' which does something similiar but you must choose points to read in, the automated version is better.  Other suggested approaches were to change to a tiff or matrix object and use MATLAB,OCTAVE or GRASS to get the matrix coordinates that match the color target, but this approach was more user friendly

also will export straight to plotly to allow quick custom versions [image]

Comment: could you add a short recording of the above? Looks interesting