# How to get a table from power BI dashboard using web scraping in R

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I am working on a data extraction task using `R`. The data is allocated in a power BI dashboard so it is very troublesome to get that. I found I solution here on SO:

[Scrape website's Power BI dashboard using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286279/scrape-websites-power-bi-dashboard-using-r)

But I am not sure on how to navigate in my page to get the components and extract the tables. My code is next:

```
library(wdman)
library(RSelenium)
library(xml2)
library(selectr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# using wdman to start a selenium server
remDr <- rsDriver(
  port = 4445L,
  browser = "firefox"
)
#remDr$open()
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L,browser = "firefox")

# open a new Tab on Chrome
remDr$open()

# navigate to the site you wish to analyze
report_url <- "https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOGI5Yzg2MGYtZmNkNy00ZjA5LTlhYTYtZTJjNjg2NTY2YTlmIiwidCI6ImI1NDE0YTdiLTcwYTYtNGUyYi05Yzc0LTM1Yjk0MDkyMjk3MCJ9"
remDr$navigate(report_url)

# fetch the data
data_table <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>%
  querySelector("div.pivotTable")
```

Although the selenium process work, I do not know how to get my table:

[image]

The arrows in blue show the tables I want, then I need to move to other pages to extract the remaining tables. But I think if I can do for the first page, the other pages would be the same.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These tables are a bit tricky because the new rows only appear in the page source code once you scroll to activate them. My solution is a function that scrapes row by row and individually adds to the overall dataframes, scrolling if necessary. It takes as input the visual-container number of the Power BI table.

Here are solutions in R:

```r
library(wdman)
library(RSelenium)

selServ <- selenium(
  port = 4444L,
  version = 'latest',
  chromever = '103.0.5060.134', # set to available
)

remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = 'localhost',
  port = 4444L,
  browserName = 'chrome'
)

scrape_powerbi_table <- function(container_number) {
  table_xpath <- paste("//*[@id='pvExplorationHost']/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container[",
                       container_number, "]/transform/div/div[3]/div/visual-modern", sep = "")
  Sys.sleep(1)
  try({scroll_button <- remDr$findElement("xpath", paste(table_xpath, "/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]", sep = ""))
    remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = scroll_button)}, silent = TRUE)
  col_names <- remDr$findElements("xpath", paste(table_xpath, "/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div", sep = ""))
  col_names <- vapply(col_names, function(x) stringr::str_split(x$getElementAttribute('innerHTML')[[1]], "<")[[1]][1], character(1))
  df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(col_names), nrow = 0))
  colnames(df) <- col_names
  more_rows_left <- TRUE
  row_count <- 2
  while (more_rows_left == TRUE) {
    data <- remDr$findElements("xpath", paste(table_xpath, "/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[@aria-rowindex='", row_count, "']/div", sep = ""))
    current_row <- vapply(data, function(x) x$getElementAttribute('innerHTML')[[1]], character(1))
    current_row <- current_row[2:length(current_row)]
    if (length(current_row) == 0 | all(is.na(current_row))) {
      tryCatch({for (i in seq(10)) scroll_button$click()
        data <- remDr$findElements("xpath", paste(table_xpath, "/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[@aria-rowindex='", row_count, "']/div", sep = ""))
        current_row <- vapply(data, function(x) x$getElementAttribute('innerHTML')[[1]], character(1))
        current_row <- current_row[2:length(current_row)]
        }, error = function (e) break)
    }
    if (length(current_row) == 0 | all(is.na(current_row))) {break}
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] <- current_row
    row_count <- row_count + 1
  }
  df
}

remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOGI5Yzg2MGYtZmNkNy00ZjA5LTlhYTYtZTJjNjg2NTY2YTlmIiwidCI6ImI1NDE0YTdiLTcwYTYtNGUyYi05Yzc0LTM1Yjk0MDkyMjk3MCJ9")
Sys.sleep(15)
next_button <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//*[@id='embedWrapperID']/div[2]/logo-bar/div/div/div/logo-bar-navigation/span/button[2]")

df1 <- scrape_powerbi_table(8)
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = next_button)
next_button$click()
df2 <- scrape_powerbi_table(8)
df3 <- scrape_powerbi_table(9)
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = next_button)
next_button$click()
next_button$click()
df4 <- scrape_powerbi_table(5)
df5 <- scrape_powerbi_table(7)
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = next_button)
next_button$click()
df6 <- scrape_powerbi_table(9)
df7 <- scrape_powerbi_table(10)
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = next_button)
next_button$click()
next_button$click()
df8 <- scrape_powerbi_table(2)
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = next_button)
next_button$click()
df9 <- scrape_powerbi_table(5)
df10 <- scrape_powerbi_table(6)

# > df9
#      Zona                      Provincia Total Establecimientos
# 1  ZONA 1                         CARCHI                      8
# 2  ZONA 1                     ESMERALDAS                      6
# 3  ZONA 1                       IMBABURA                     32
# 4  ZONA 1                      SUCUMBIOS                     27
# 5  ZONA 2                           NAPO                      9
# 6  ZONA 2                       ORELLANA                     30
# 7  ZONA 2                      PICHINCHA                     63
# 8  ZONA 3                     CHIMBORAZO                     56
# 9  ZONA 3                       COTOPAXI                     54
# 10 ZONA 3                        PASTAZA                     13
# 11 ZONA 3                     TUNGURAHUA                    122
# 12 ZONA 4                         MANABI                    127
# 13 ZONA 4 SANTO DOMINGO DE LOS TSACHILAS                     49
# 14 ZONA 5                        BOLIVAR                     24
# 15 ZONA 5                      GALAPAGOS                      5
# 16 ZONA 5                         GUAYAS                     27
# 17 ZONA 5                       LOS RIOS                     53
# 18 ZONA 5                    SANTA ELENA                     18
# 19 ZONA 6                          AZUAY                    182
# 20 ZONA 6                          CAÑAR                     35
# 21 ZONA 6                MORONA SANTIAGO                     23
# 22 ZONA 7                         EL ORO                     65
# 23 ZONA 7                           LOJA                     48
# 24 ZONA 7               ZAMORA CHINCHIPE                     16
# 25 ZONA 8                         GUAYAS                     86
# 26 ZONA 9                      PICHINCHA                    309
```

And in Python:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOGI5Yzg2MGYtZmNkNy00ZjA5LTlhYTYtZTJjNjg2NTY2YTlmIiwidCI6ImI1NDE0YTdiLTcwYTYtNGUyYi05Yzc0LTM1Yjk0MDkyMjk3MCJ9")

def scrape_powerbi_table(visual_container_number):
    table_xpath = "//*[@id='pvExplorationHost']/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container[" + str(visual_container_number) + "]/transform/div/div[3]/div/visual-modern"
    scroll_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, table_xpath + "/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]")))
    col_names = [i.text for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, table_xpath + "/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div")]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
    more_rows_left = True
    row_count = 2
    while more_rows_left == True:
        data = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, table_xpath + "/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[@aria-rowindex='" + str(row_count) + "']/div")
        current_row = [i.get_attribute("innerHTML") for i in data][1:]
        if not current_row:
            try:
                for i in range(10):
                    scroll_button.click()
                data = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, table_xpath + "/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[@aria-rowindex='" + str(row_count) + "']/div")
                current_row = [i.get_attribute("innerHTML") for i in data][1:]
            except Exception:
                break
        if not current_row:
            break
        df.loc[len(df)] = current_row
        row_count += 1
    return df

next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='embedWrapperID']/div[2]/logo-bar/div/div/div/logo-bar-navigation/span/button[2]")))

df1 = scrape_powerbi_table(8)
next_button.click()
df2 = scrape_powerbi_table(8)
df3 = scrape_powerbi_table(9)
next_button.click()
next_button.click()
df4 = scrape_powerbi_table(5)
df5 = scrape_powerbi_table(7)
next_button.click()
df6 = scrape_powerbi_table(9)
df7 = scrape_powerbi_table(10)
next_button.click()
next_button.click()
df8 = scrape_powerbi_table(2)
next_button.click()
df9 = scrape_powerbi_table(5)
df10 = scrape_powerbi_table(6)

driver.quit()
```

Also, here are the ten files in csv format for your convenience.

https://mega.nz/folder/LtVDiCyQ#5iW1mkd1VVTmcPApeqfGFA

Comment: Hi many thanks! I am looking for a solution in `R`. I will upvote!

Comment: Hello, I have updated my answer with a full R solution as well. Let me know if that works!

Comment: Magnificent, just let me check the function and I will award you the bounty ASAP.

Comment: It works perfectly, I just have a question, the function you did could it works for similar dashboards, or it is only for this particular dashboard?

Comment: It would work just fine with some mild fine tuning and preparation. All you have to do is find the visual-container number of each table, and fill in the `next_button$click()`s accordingly if there are any pages skipped. You can find the visual-container number of each table by inspecting on Google Chrome, clicking on table text, right clicking the corresponding code, selecting copy XPath, and selecting the number after visual-container.

Comment: Hi, hoping you are fine. I am trying to use your amazing solution for a new dashboard: https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYTg3YTkxZWQtOGIyNy00ODJlLTk4ZmItNDMzZjU5NTYyZWQ5IiwidCI6IjcwNjIyMGRiLTliMjktNGU5MS1hODI1LTI1NmIwNmQyNjlmMyJ9&pageName=ReportSection but I can not find a way to get the the names and numbers of tables as well as the id of containers to extract. I am trying to get tables from `Número de emergencias según establecimiento` and table before map but I am not able to do. Maybe if you have time could you please give a check? Many thanks!

Comment: I tried running the python code and there was an error on the part of the code locating the scroll button. Do you know if something has changed since this answer was written, for example the syntax? Regardless of what has changed, how do I locate and identify the scroll button? I don't visibly see it with my eyes so maybe the scroll button is hidden somewhere on the page, but I'm not sure. I see you identify the xpath to the scroll button but that doesn't seem to be working for me. Any guidance on how to identify the scroll button?