# Data Scraping a Power BI Dashboard using R

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a .csv of a data set on this Power BI Dashboard using Selenium in R. The dashboard is [here](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNmY4MTQyN2YtNTMyOC00NWMyLTk0ZWUtNDA1ZTllNDZlMTE0IiwidCI6IjZiY2NiNTZkLWI1YTQtNDkzOC05MGRhLTNhNDE4ZjA0MDJjYyIsImMiOjF9&pageName=ReportSection787ec227054b3e646910)

I'm having issues scraping the data into the appropriate columns and I need to scroll to view more of the data in order to scrape the entire list.

The code I'm currently trying can pull from the table, but it creates a disorganized and incomplete dataset. I'm struggling with finding a solution on how to cleanly scrape this dashboard and add a scrolling component into my R code. The code I'm using is referenced from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286279/scrape-websites-power-bi-dashboard-using-r).

Here is my current R code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)

library(wdman)
library(RSelenium)
library(xml2)
library(selectr)


selServ <- selenium(
  port = 4444L,
  version = 'latest',
  chromever = '105.0.5195.19')

remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = 'localhost',
  port = 4444L,
  browserName = 'chrome'
)

remDr$open()

report_url <- "https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNmY4MTQyN2YtNTMyOC00NWMyLTk0ZWUtNDA1ZTllNDZlMTE0IiwidCI6IjZiY2NiNTZkLWI1YTQtNDkzOC05MGRhLTNhNDE4ZjA0MDJjYyIsImMiOjF9&pageName=ReportSection787ec227054b3e646910"
remDr$navigate(report_url)

zipcode_data_table <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>%
  querySelector("div.tableEx")

col_headers <- zipcode_data_table %>%
  querySelectorAll("div.columnHeaders div.pivotTableCellWrap") %>%
  map_chr(xml_text)

zipcode_data <- zipcode_data_table %>%
  querySelectorAll("div.bodyCells div.pivotTableCellWrap") %>%
  map(xml_parent) %>%
  unique() %>%
  map(~ .x %>% querySelectorAll("div.pivotTableCellWrap") %>% map_chr(xml_text)) %>%
  bind_cols()

df_final <- tibble(final = col_headers, zipcode_data) %>%
  type_convert(trim_ws = T, na = c(""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to extract the rows of the table with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
url <- "https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNmY4MTQyN2YtNTMyOC00NWMyLTk0ZWUtNDA1ZTllNDZlMTE0IiwidCI6IjZiY2NiNTZkLWI1YTQtNDkzOC05MGRhLTNhNDE4ZjA0MDJjYyIsImMiOjF9&pageName=ReportSection787ec227054b3e646910"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

Sys.sleep(5)

remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(x = 1035, y = 650)
list_Table <- list()

counter <- 1

for(l in 0 : 30)
{
  if(l %% 10 == 0)
  {
    web_Obj_Table <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '/html/body/div[1]/report-embed/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/exploration-container/div/docking-container/div/div/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas/div/div[2]/div/div[2]')
    vector_Info <- strsplit(web_Obj_Table$getElementText()[[1]], "\n")[[1]]
    vector_Info <- vector_Info[-(1 : 22)]
    nb_Item <- length(vector_Info)
    list_Row_Table <- list()
    counter_Temp <- 1
    
    for(i in 1 : nb_Item)
    {
      list_Row_Table[[counter_Temp]] <- ""
      
      if(stringr::str_detect(vector_Info[i], "\\d{5,9}") == TRUE)
      {
        list_Row_Table[[counter_Temp]] <- paste0(list_Row_Table[[counter_Temp]], ";;;", vector_Info[i])
        counter_Temp <- counter_Temp + 1    
      }else
      {
        list_Row_Table[[counter_Temp - 1]] <- paste0(list_Row_Table[[counter_Temp - 1]],  ";;;", vector_Info[i])
      }
    }
    
    list_Row_Table <- lapply(X = list_Row_Table, FUN = function(x) strsplit(x, ";;;")[[1]])
    list_Table[[counter]] <- do.call("rbind", list_Row_Table)
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
  
  print(l)
  remDr$doubleclick()
}

list_Table
[[1]]
      [,1] [,2]     [,3]                                              [,4]               [,5]          [,6]       [,7]         [,8]     
 [1,] ""   " 10100" "Meghna Knit Composite Ltd."                      "Gazipur"          "Bangladesh"  "Gold"     "2023-05-03" "Apparel"
 [2,] ""   " 10236" "Sein Together International Philippines Inc."    "Rosario"          "Philippines" "Platinum" "2024-02-22" "Apparel"
 [3,] ""   " 10261" "Shiva Kriti Exports"                             "Gurgaon"          "India"       "Gold"     "2023-09-13" "Apparel"
 [4,] ""   " 10322" "Multifabs Limited"                               "Konabari"         "Bangladesh"  "Gold"     "2023-07-25" "Apparel"
 [5,] ""   " 10325" "El Nasr Clothing And Textiles Company (Kabo)"    "Alexandria"       "Egypt"       "Gold"     "2023-03-14" "Apparel"
 [6,] ""   " 10335" "Chi Dat Garment Co. Ltd"                         "Duc Hoa District" "Vietnam"     "Gold"     "2023-05-19" "Apparel"
 [7,] ""   " 10582" "Asrotex Ltd."                                    "Gazipur"          "Bangladesh"  "Gold"     "2022-11-24" "Apparel"
 [8,] ""   " 10692" "M. I. Industries"                                "Karachi"          "Pakistan"    "Gold"     "2022-11-12" "Apparel"
 [9,] ""   " 10721" "Anhui Lujiang Xingshen Leather Co., Ltd."        "Lujiang County"   "China"       "Gold"     "2022-09-28" "Apparel"
[10,] ""   " 10850" "Tosrifa Industries Ltd."                         "Gazipur"          "Bangladesh"  "Gold"     "2023-01-31" "Apparel"
[11,] ""   " 10856" "Best Shirts Ltd."                                "Joydebpur"        "Bangladesh"  "Gold"     "2023-03-14" "Apparel"
[12,] ""   " 10874" "Smart Shirts (Lanka) Limited - Pallekele"        "Pallekele"        "Sri Lanka"   "Gold"     "2023-04-28" "Apparel"
[13,] ""   " 10913" "JiangYin Taidi Garments Co. Ltd"                 "Jiangyin"         "China"       "Gold"     "2023-03-16" "Apparel"
[14,] ""   " 11046" "P.N. Composite Ltd"                              "Gazipur"          "Bangladesh"  "Gold"     "2023-02-08" "Apparel"
[15,] ""   " 11128" "Weihai Cechic Textiles And Garments Co., Ltd."   "Weihai"           "China"       "Gold"     "2023-02-16" "Apparel"
[16,] ""   " 11141" "Jadeluck International Co. Ltd"                  "Hochiminh"        "Vietnam"     "Gold"     "2022-11-18" "Apparel"
[17,] ""   " 11258" "Shengzhou Jialan Garments and Apparel Co., Ltd." "Shengzhou City"   "China"       "Gold"     "2023-03-30" "Apparel"
[18,] ""   " 11392" "Delta Textile Egypt"                             "Nasr City"        "Egypt"       "Gold"     "2022-09-29" "Apparel"
[19,] ""   " 11510" "Konffetty S.A. de C.V."                          "Apopa"            "El Salvador" "Platinum" "2022-10-09" "Apparel"
[20,] ""   " 11586" "Marina Apparels Ltd."                            "Dhaka"            "Bangladesh"  "Gold"     "2022-11-08" "Apparel"
      [,9]
 [1,] ""  
 [2,] ""  
 [3,] ""  
 [4,] ""  
 [5,] ""  
 [6,] ""  
 [7,] ""  
 [8,] ""  
 [9,] ""  
[10,] ""  
[11,] ""  
[12,] ""  
[13,] ""  
[14,] ""  
[15,] ""  
[16,] ""  
[17,] ""  
[18,] ""  
[19,] ""  
[20,] " " 

[[2]]
      [,1] [,2]      [,3]                                              [,4]                [,5]          [,6]       [,7]         [,8]     
 [1,] ""   " 11128"  "Weihai Cechic Textiles And Garments Co., Ltd."   "Weihai"            "China"       "Gold"     "2023-02-16" "Apparel"
 [2,] ""   " 11141"  "Jadeluck International Co. Ltd"                  "Hochiminh"         "Vietnam"     "Gold"     "2022-11-18" "Apparel"
 [3,] ""   " 11258"  "Shengzhou Jialan Garments and Apparel Co., Ltd." "Shengzhou City"    "China"       "Gold"     "2023-03-30" "Apparel"
 [4,] ""   " 11392"  "Delta Textile Egypt"                             "Nasr City"         "Egypt"       "Gold"     "2022-09-29" "Apparel"
 [5,] ""   " 11510"  "Konffetty S.A. de C.V."                          "Apopa"             "El Salvador" "Platinum" "2022-10-09" "Apparel"
 [6,] ""   " 11586"  "Marina Apparels Ltd."                            "Dhaka"             "Bangladesh"  "Gold"     "2022-11-08" "Apparel"
 [7,] ""   " 11640"  "Turag Garments & Hosiery Mills Ltd."             "Gazipur"           "Bangladesh"  "Gold"     "2023-05-13" "Apparel"
 [8,] ""   " 11801"  "Dong Bang Vina Co . Ltd"                         "Ho Chi Minh"       "Vietnam"     "Gold"     "2023-01-25" "Apparel"
 [9,] ""   " 11899"  "Lexi (Ningbo) Garment Co. Ltd."                  "Ningbo City"       "China"       "Gold"     "2023-09-09" "Apparel"
[10,] ""   " 11992"  "Esses Fashions Limited"                          "Gazipur"           "Bangladesh"  "Gold"     "2023-07-12" "Apparel"
[11,] ""   " 12055"  "MA'AM Arts"                                      "Jaipur"            "India"       "Platinum" "2024-04-06" "Apparel"
[12,] ""   " 12258"  "Taicang Longhui Garment Co. Ltd."                "Taicang"           "China"       "Gold"     "2023-07-27" "Apparel"
[13,] ""   " 12343"  "Umar Textiles"                                   "Karachi"           "Pakistan"    "Gold"     "2023-07-13" "Textile"
[14,] ""   " 124197" "Minh Anh - Do Luong Garment Joint Stock Company" "Do Luong District" "Vietnam"     "Gold"     "2023-03-24" "Apparel"
[15,] ""   " 124214" "Medline Assembly France SAS"                     "Châteaubriant"     "France"      "Gold"     "2023-09-01" "Other"  
[16,] ""   " 125056" "Jiangsu Jiawin Garment Co., Ltd."                "Suqian"            "China"       "Gold"     "2023-08-05" "Apparel"
[17,] ""   " 125516" "Cobes Industries (Bago) Co., Ltd."               "BAGO"              "Myanmar"     "Gold"     "2022-12-09" "Apparel"
[18,] ""   " 125765" "PT SH Garment"                                   "Purwakarta"        "Indonesia"   "Gold"     "2023-09-01" "Apparel"
[19,] ""   " 12663"  "Valmont Fashions Ltd."                           "Gazipur"           "Bangladesh"  "Gold"     "2023-01-25" "Apparel"
[20,] ""   " 126964" "Van Phu Garment Joint Stock Company"             "NA"                "Vietnam"     "Gold"     "2023-09-14" "Apparel"
      [,9]
 [1,] ""  
 [2,] ""  
 [3,] ""  
 [4,] ""  
 [5,] ""  
 [6,] ""  
 [7,] ""  
 [8,] ""  
 [9,] ""  
[10,] ""  
[11,] ""  
[12,] ""  
[13,] ""  
[14,] ""  
[15,] ""  
[16,] ""  
[17,] ""  
[18,] ""  
[19,] ""  
[20,] " " 

[[3]]
      [,1] [,2]      [,3]                                              [,4]                [,5]         [,6]       [,7]         [,8]     
 [1,] ""   " 124197" "Minh Anh - Do Luong Garment Joint Stock Company" "Do Luong District" "Vietnam"    "Gold"     "2023-03-24" "Apparel"
 [2,] ""   " 124214" "Medline Assembly France SAS"                     "Châteaubriant"     "France"     "Gold"     "2023-09-01" "Other"  
 [3,] ""   " 125056" "Jiangsu Jiawin Garment Co., Ltd."                "Suqian"            "China"      "Gold"     "2023-08-05" "Apparel"
 [4,] ""   " 125516" "Cobes Industries (Bago) Co., Ltd."               "BAGO"              "Myanmar"    "Gold"     "2022-12-09" "Apparel"
 [5,] ""   " 125765" "PT SH Garment"                                   "Purwakarta"        "Indonesia"  "Gold"     "2023-09-01" "Apparel"
 [6,] ""   " 12663"  "Valmont Fashions Ltd."                           "Gazipur"           "Bangladesh" "Gold"     "2023-01-25" "Apparel"
 [7,] ""   " 126964" "Van Phu Garment Joint Stock Company"             "NA"                "Vietnam"    "Gold"     "2023-09-14" "Apparel"
 [8,] ""   " 12725"  "Kayser-Roth Lumberton"                           "Lumberton"         "USA"        "Platinum" "2023-10-21" "Apparel"
 [9,] ""   " 127847" "Sri Senthil Balaji Tex LLP Unit 2"               "Erode"             "India"      "Gold"     "2023-07-15" "Apparel"
[10,] ""   " 12814"  "Kashion Industry Co. Ltd."                       "Ningbo"            "China"      "Gold"     "2023-02-09" "Apparel"
[11,] ""   " 128316" "Sultana Sweaters Ltd."                           "Mymensingh"        "Bangladesh" "Gold"     "2023-01-11" "Apparel"
[12,] ""   " 128553" "Changzhou Dongtai Garment Co., Ltd."             "Changzhou City"    "China"      "Gold"     "2023-02-02" "Apparel"
[13,] ""   " 128684" "HQ Printing Company Limited"                     "Nam Dinh"          "Vietnam"    "Gold"     "2023-04-05" "Other"  
[14,] ""   " 128765" "A I Enterprises Pvt. Ltd."                       "Chennai"           "India"      "Gold"     "2023-07-19" "Apparel"
[15,] ""   " 128780" "Nanchang Hongyang Garment Co., Ltd."             "Nanchang"          "China"      "Gold"     "2023-06-01" "Apparel"
[16,] ""   " 129103" "Trident Limited"                                 "Sehore"            "India"      "Gold"     "2023-07-20" "Apparel"
[17,] ""   " 13226"  "Vinh Thanh Garment Export Co. Ltd."              "Huyen Cu Chi"      "Vietnam"    "Gold"     "2023-07-29" "Apparel"
[18,] ""   " 13319"  "Guangdong Ruiyuan Technology Co. Ltd."           "Puning"            "China"      "Gold"     "2023-04-13" "Apparel"
[19,] ""   " 13684"  "Wuhu Huayang Clothing Group Co., Ltd."           "wuhu"              "China"      "Gold"     "2023-09-14" "Apparel"
[20,] ""   " 13738"  "Sonic Textile Industries"                        "Karachi"           "Pakistan"   "Gold"     "2023-04-26" "Apparel"
      [,9]
 [1,] ""  
 [2,] ""  
 [3,] ""  
 [4,] ""  
 [5,] ""  
 [6,] ""  
 [7,] ""  
 [8,] ""  
 [9,] ""  
[10,] ""  
[11,] ""  
[12,] ""  
[13,] ""  
[14,] ""  
[15,] ""  
[16,] ""  
[17,] ""  
[18,] ""  
[19,] ""  
[20,] " " 

[[4]]
      [,1] [,2]      [,3]                                                [,4]                  [,5]         [,6]   [,7]        
 [1,] ""   " 128780" "Nanchang Hongyang Garment Co., Ltd."               "Nanchang"            "China"      "Gold" "2023-06-01"
 [2,] ""   " 129103" "Trident Limited"                                   "Sehore"              "India"      "Gold" "2023-07-20"
 [3,] ""   " 13226"  "Vinh Thanh Garment Export Co. Ltd."                "Huyen Cu Chi"        "Vietnam"    "Gold" "2023-07-29"
 [4,] ""   " 13319"  "Guangdong Ruiyuan Technology Co. Ltd."             "Puning"              "China"      "Gold" "2023-04-13"
 [5,] ""   " 13684"  "Wuhu Huayang Clothing Group Co., Ltd."             "wuhu"                "China"      "Gold" "2023-09-14"
 [6,] ""   " 13738"  "Sonic Textile Industries"                          "Karachi"             "Pakistan"   "Gold" "2023-04-26"
 [7,] ""   " 13812"  "Ceiba Textiles S de R L"                           "San Pedro Sula"      "Honduras"   "Gold" "2023-04-18"
 [8,] ""   " 13831"  "Wuhu Seduno Fashion Co. Ltd"                       "wuhu"                "China"      "Gold" "2023-08-26"
 [9,] ""   " 13836"  "Velocity Jeans Egypt for Readymade Garments (ESC)" "Ismailia"            "Egypt"      "Gold" "2023-06-06"
[10,] ""   " 13899"  "Xiamen Yangli Garment Co., Ltd."                   "Xiamen"              "China"      "Gold" "2023-08-22"
[11,] ""   " 13959"  "Fruit of the Loom Textile - Fruit 1"               "Sale"                "Morocco"    "Gold" "2022-12-15"
[12,] ""   " 14005"  "Dragoni Fashions Ltd."                             "Chittagong"          "Bangladesh" "Gold" "2023-09-07"
[13,] ""   " 14177"  "Hwa Meei Optical Co. Ltd"                          "Tainan"              "Taiwan"     "Gold" "2022-12-20"
[14,] ""   " 14253"  "Mastrade International Garments Ltd."              "Gazipur"             "Bangladesh" "Gold" "2023-01-07"
[15,] ""   " 14428"  "Expack Corrugated Cartons PLC"                     "Kelaniya"            "Sri Lanka"  "Gold" "2023-03-04"
[16,] ""   " 14453"  "Nanchang New Huarui Clothing Co. Ltd."             "Nanchang City"       "China"      "Gold" "2022-12-02"
[17,] ""   " 14595"  "Talisman Ltd."                                     "Ashulia Savar Dhaka" "Bangladesh" "Gold" "2023-06-06"
[18,] ""   " 14603"  "Walt Technology Group Co., Ltd."                   "Haining"             "China"      "Gold" "2023-09-21"
[19,] ""   " 14649"  "Columbus Apparel (Cambodia) Inc."                  "Phnom Penh"          "Cambodia"   "Gold" "2023-06-02"
[20,] ""   " 14699"  "Lilly Billy (Thailand) Co. Ltd."                   "Bangkok"             "Thailand"   "Gold" "2023-04-11"
      [,8]                [,9]
 [1,] "Apparel"           ""  
 [2,] "Apparel"           ""  
 [3,] "Apparel"           ""  
 [4,] "Apparel"           ""  
 [5,] "Apparel"           ""  
 [6,] "Apparel"           ""  
 [7,] "Apparel"           ""  
 [8,] "Apparel"           ""  
 [9,] "Apparel"           ""  
[10,] "Apparel"           ""  
[11,] "Apparel"           ""  
[12,] "Apparel"           ""  
[13,] "Apparel"           ""  
[14,] "Apparel"           ""  
[15,] "Apparel, Footwear" ""  
[16,] "Apparel"           ""  
[17,] "Apparel"           ""  
[18,] "Apparel"           ""  
[19,] "Apparel"           ""  
[20,] "Apparel"           " "
```

Comment: Thank you @Emmanuel Hamel , I managed to run the code successfully once. After that, when I re-run the code, the list_table content repeats itself 4 times in a row, creating 4 copies of the 20 rows that begin with "Meghna Knit Composite Ltd." in row 1. I think the remDr$moveMousetoLocation command might be causing the issues because when I run the command, it comes back as 'NULL'. I'm not 100% sure though that is the issue. My end goal is to scrape this entire list, so I'm guessing that if the code runs correctly, I can continually run this loop until the table is fully scraped.

Comment: On my end, I have been able to get the content of the entire table with this code with "l in 0 : 20000". Maybe you can change the location of the mouse with the command remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(x = new_X_Position, y = new_Y_Position). The position of the button to scroll down in the PowerBI can be different on your computer. Also, you might have some duplicates of some rows in the output. In this code, I assumed that 10 clicks are needed on the scroll button to scroll down. You can just remove the duplicates with the function dplyr::distinct.

Comment: You can get the content of the entire table even if there are some duplicates from time to time.

Comment: Thank you! Changing the mouse location fixed it on my end.